# Circular referencing with three .NET class libraries - possible or stupid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reference, class-library

I have read other questions about circular references on here but I can't find the answer to my question.

I have three class libraries: Authentication, EmailService and ExceptionService.

Authentication controls user login to various applications, EmailService sends emails, the ExceptionService logs errors/exceptions to a database.

At the moment Authentication references the EmailService and the ExceptionService, to use their functionality, and this works. The ExceptionService references the EmailService to send report emails. All is well.

What I would like to know is if the following is possible/advisable/stupid, and if there is a better way to do it:

- I want the EmailService to be able to use the functionality of the ExceptionService, so any errors in the EmailService are reported. In theory this could mean that the ExcpetionService would then call back to the EmailService to send the reporting email, which may trigger the same error, so I would have to write a method that was used by the EmailService only which did not send the email, only logged it.
- The ExceptionService should still reference the EmailService.
- The Authentication class library should also still use both of the other services.

This all sounds very complicated and circular, which is why I think it might not be a good thing to do. But what should I do instead?

I have tried referencing the ExceptionService in the EmailService, but it then will not compile when I create a private ExceptionService object and try to use it.

I suppose what I really want is for any of my applications to reference the EmailService and ExceptionService, but for them to also reference each other.

The only way of solving this that I have found so far is to forget about reporting exceptions in the EmailService.

Many thanks for your help :)

Comment: Why not have a 3rd party utility like Log4net handle your exception logging?  You can configure log4net to send emails as a logging output.

Comment: use NLog for logging its the best option it can also send emails

Comment: If services depend directly on other services for non-core functionality, the design is flawed. It would be better to use a service bus to communicate between services. Explaining that in detail is beyond the scope of a comment, but check out MassTransit or NServiceBus. Basically every service sends messages to the Service Bus, and can read messages from that Bus. For instance, the Error service could send an Error message to the Bus, which would then be picked up by the Email service to create an email message about it and send it. This way there are no direct dependencies between services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are having problems is because you are tightly coupling your classes and the compiler very sensibly gets upset when you try to create a circular coupling. You could solve this by making interfaces for your services and supplying an instance of the interface of one service to the implementation of the other and vice versa.

A much better solution though would be to cease reinventing the wheel and to use an existing logging framework. Both [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) and [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) will meet your logging and emailing needs.

Comment: I have suggested the same to her..but NLog is much better plz suggest it more

Comment: So would the best idea to be to get my ExcpetionService to use NLog (or similar) so I do not have to change all apps if we were to change to a different logger in the future, and use the email on that to send email reports. Then my EmailService would just be used for other emails. That way only the EmailService need to reference the ExceptionService (NLog) and not vice-versa.

Comment: @tekiegirl Without knowing the full details, I can't say for sure, but that does sound a good first step at least.

Comment: @DavidArno I have started looking at NLog, as I think this is the right way to go. I am creating a class library as a wrapper for NLog, and it will not need to reference the EmailService, but the EmailService can use it to log its own errors. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Merge the assemblies. It is a common mistake to split a project into as many assemblies as possible. This adds management burden and causes trouble in case of cyclic references. Tight coupling is to be avoided, but it cannot be entirely avoided. Accept it.

Your situation is a valid case of a cyclic reference. The two classes just need each other for logical reasons.

You can resolve the cyclic reference issue with interfaces, but the dependencies still exists at runtime. The interfaces do not improve code quality, they just shut up the compiler warnings.

Do not manage dependencies with assemblies. Use namespaces and folders. Assemblies are deployment units, not dependency management tools.

Comment: "The interfaces do not improve code quality, they just shut up the compiler warnings". Interfaces reduce coupling and thus improve code quality.

Comment: @DavidArno Less coupling means being able to modify one part of the code without the other. An interface with a single implementor does not help with that. If you disagree, in what way does it help? Also, if interfaces helped just like that, why not do a mass refactoring and convert everything to interfaces? That is clearly not useful.

Comment: If you have designed a tightly coupled system due to "just accepting it", then the code is likely to be of poor quality in many ways. So just refactoring to add interfaces won't magically make it good code. Code designed with loose coupling though is likely to be well designed in other ways: with smaller classes and methods, good unit tests, good abstractions and data hiding and the like. Interfaces with single implementers aids hugely in unit testing for example as it becomes easy to mock parts of the system to simplify tests.

Comment: @DavidArno you're right in everything you just said. The OP's case is one where interfaces would not resolve any runtime coupling. They "resolve" the compile-time coupling by shutting off the cycle check. Whether the two classes call each other using a call or a vcall instruction changes nothing about what they do and expect from each other. The coupling stays the same, just hidden now. It is fundamental to his requirements that mailing and logging use each other. I have been in the exact same situation, btw, in a project of mine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you uses concrete classes, not interfaces. So, my proposition is to introduce two interfaces i.e.:*IExceptionService*, *IEmailService* and place them in the separate project e.g.: *Services*. Projects containing implementations of these two services will reference this new project. Thanks to that *ExceptionService* can use *IEmailService* and *EmailService* can use *IExceptionService*. At the same time *ExceptionService* and *EmailService* can be defined in different assemblies.

What is important *ExceptionService* and *EmailService* shoudn't be aware what is behind these interfaces. The concrete implementations should be somehow **injected** into them. In order to do that you can use dependency injection container. If you don't want to use another new library, you can also implement simple service locator.

Answer (score -1):

(I'm ignoring the AuthenticationService for now because it only muddles the issue - what you have is a simple circular dependency between two services - Exception and Email).

The best way to solve these circular dependency issues is by using a layer of interfaces and a repository.

Lets say you have two classes, `EmailService` and `ExceptionService`. They can't reference each other's DLL, so what you do, you create a third assembly, `Interfaces`, and create two interfaces for them, `IEmailService` and `IExceptionService`. Now your two classes can both reference only that shared Interfaces assembly.

Using some sort of [Inversion of Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) mechanism, your `EmailService` gets a reference to a `IExceptionService`, and vice versa, and thus the circle is broken.

One simple IoC mechanism is the Service Locator pattern. Create this (simplified) object:

```
public class ServiceLocator
{
     public static IEmailService EmailService {get;set;}
     public static IExceptionService ExceptionService {get;set;}
}
```

Now your EmailService, on startup, can register itself with the ServiceLocator, and allow other classes to get a reference to it, without having a dependency on its assembly.

Of course, most IoC solutions have a bit more to them than that, but that's the basic idea - prevent circular dependencies by extracting shared interfaces into a shared assembly, and reference only that.

Comment: "Dependency Injection mechanism is the Service Locator pattern". Um, no. DI means *injecting* dependencies, not by exposing through "global variables" such as the service locator pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can see how this would work if my services were classes within one class library, but they are separate. In that case the Interface would be a separate class library which would need to reference both the email and exception libraries, therefore creating more circles. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @tekiegirl The Interfaces would sit in a separate class library, but it won't need any reference to the Email and Exception libraries - only they will have a reference to it.