# Best pattern for avoiding circular reference when using models in interfaces

Tags: .net, architecture, interface

I often end up with code similar to that below, which would lead to a circular reference in Visual Studio:

(these two namespaces exists in separate assemblies)

```
namespace Data
{
    public class DataContext : IDataContext
    {
        public IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPeople()
        {
            // Get all people here
        }
    }
}


namespace Interfaces
{
    public interface IDataContext
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> GetAllPeople();
    }
}
```

Both the interface (IDataContext) and it's implementation (DataContext) are dependent on a model named `Person`.

In order to avoid a circular reference (which Visual Studio does not allow), I think have a couple of options:

1. Move the model into a separate `Models` assembly and add this as a reference to both the `Interfaces` and `Data` assemblies.
2. Have the `Person` model implement an interface (e.g. `IPerson`), which would exist in the `Interfaces` assembly, and use this in place of `Person` in both the interface and it's implementation.

Having a separate assembly to contain a few small models seems wasteful, as does creating an interface for a model that only contains properties.

What is the most widely accepted way to do this?

Comment: Do you *need* the interfaces and implementations to be in separate assemblies? Do you ever deploy one and not the other? If not, put everything in the same assembly.
http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/12/08/advices-on-partitioning-code-through-net-assemblies/

Comment: Here's my take on a very similar situation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20883444/122718 TL;DR: merge the assemblies if possible.

Comment: @IanNelson No, but in more complicated projects where interfaces depend on each other we have found that it could lead to more circular reference problems to have the interface reside with the implementation. At least this way the interfaces assembly only needs to be dependent on itself (and, potentially, the models assembly).

Comment: To my mind, it smacks of premature decomposition to physically separate types in this way. I'd stick everything in a single assembly - models, interfaces, implementation, the whole shebang. Of course I would use namespaces appropriately for *logical* grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are perfectly fine, picking one depends on your preferences:

- If you prefer to keep the code without any modifications, and simply re-arrange the assemblies, the first approach is perfect: creating additional assemblies, no matter how small they may be, does not carry an overhead so large as to make it prohibitive.
- If you prefer programming to interfaces, the second approach is perfect: your code will be insulated from the implementing classes, making it impossible to use a method or two that were not meant to be used. As a side benefit, this would also simplify your unit testing, because substituting interface implementations for mock objects is the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Make an assembly for model, another for service interfaces, and another for service implementations.

Model classes should only depend on other model classes. Service interfaces may depend on model classes. Service implementations may depend on anything.

Comment: Those suggested rules for type dependencies are perfectly valid, but can be achieved with namespaces and folders. Is it really necessary to create separate physical deployables to enforce such practices?

Comment: I assumed separate physical deployables were part of the required solution (Maybe, because of the context where I usually work). Otherwise, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

As a trick, the model assembly should not contain references to any other assembly in your project.
Model must be totally independent.

Create all classes and their interfaces in the model assembly. 
Then place implementation on another assembly.